# Can I take your order: a Chipotle concept conund

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

Your program will take in a string from **stdin**, and output multiple lines to **stdout**.

An example of input looks like this:

My favorite Chipotle order:

> B1113YNNY

Let's break it down:

- The first character is either A (burrito), or B (burrito bowl).
- The second character is 1 (black beans), or 2 (pinto beans).
- The third character is either 1 (white rice), or 2 (brown rice).
- The fourth character is either 1 (chicken), 2 (sofritas), or 3 (steak).
- The fifth character is either 1 (mild salsa), 2 (medium salsa), or 3 (hot salsa).
- The last four characters are Y if they want the item, or N otherwise:
- character 6 is corn
- character 7 is guacamole
- character 8 is sour cream
- character 9 is cheese

A working program for this challenge will output this to **stdout**:

> burrito bowl with:
>   black beans
>   white rice
>   chicken
>   hot salsa
>   corn
>   cheese

Replace the above words with the words acquired from input.

## Clarifications.

Standard loopholes are disallowed.
You may *only* get input from stdin, and *only* put output to stdout.

Comment: We have some [Defaults for I/O](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/49110) here. Also functions instead of full programs are always allowed. Overriding those should only be done if there is a specific reason for that, which I don't see here.

Comment: May be worth removing and submitting to the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get it up to scratch?

Comment: @JonathanAllan sure

Comment: It amazes me that all answers have zero votes so far!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 293 bytes

```python
j=input();a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i=[1-ord(c)%7%5for c in j];print('\n'.join(('burrito'+[' bowl',''][a]+' with:',['pinto','black'][b]+' beans',['brown','white'][c]+' rice',['sofritas','chicken','steak'][d],['medium','mild','hot'][e]+' salsa'))+'\ncorn'*f+'\nguacamole'*g+'\nsour cream'*h+'\ncheese'*i)
```

Mostly basic lookups with a little modulo trickery for the indexes of items:
`AB123YN` yielding indexes `-1,-2,1,0,-1,1,0` respectively, and
using string multiplication for the optional items rather than a lookup.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <s>302</s> 298 bytes

```
o=input()
print"\n".join([s[0]+s[1+(ord(c)+1)%3]+s[-1]for(x,c)in zip(["burrito ,,bowl, with:",",black,pinto, beans",",white,brown, rice",",chicken,sofritas,chicken,",",mild,medium,hot, salsa"],o)for s in[x.split(",")]]+[x for(x,c)in zip(["corn","guacamole","sour cream","cheese"],o[5:])if c=="Y"])
```

EDIT: according to the [consensus on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/string-input-with-or-without/7634#7634), I'm allowed to use `input` instead of `raw_input`, requiring the user of the program to type his or her Chipotle order in quotes! Thanks, @StevenH. for informing me of this.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>336</s> 335 Bytes

```
q,i=input(),int
print"burrito "+{"A":"","B":"bowl"}[q[0]]+" with:\n"+["black","pinto"][i(q[1])-1]+" beans\n"+["white","brown"][i(q[2])-1]+" rice\n"+["chicken","sofritas","steak"][i(q[3])-1]+"\n"+["mild","medium","hot"][i(q[4])-1]+" salsa\n"+"\n".join([x for y,x in enumerate(["corn","guacamole","sour cream","cheese"]) if q[y+5]=="Y"])
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/CqXv/0)

Removed one byte by renaming `int`: `i=int`

Comment: You can save some bytes by interleaving the strings like `"wbhriotwen"[i(q[2])-1::2]`, also for black and pinto

Comment: Don't you mean raw_input?

Comment: @Omar, requiring input to be wrapped in quotation marks and escaped as would be needed for using `input()` over `raw_input()` is [allowed by meta consensus.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7634/55696)   This is especially true when the original question specifies that input is passed *as a string*, as it is here.

Comment: Ooh, excellent, @StevenH., I'll change that in my submission, then. :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, <s>445</s> 364 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
set l=call:l 
%l%"burrito with:" "burrito bowl with:"
%l%"black beans" "pinto beans" 
%l%"white rice" "brown rice" 
%l%chicken sofritas steak
%l%"mild salsa" "medium salsa" "hot salsa" 
%l%corn
%l%guacamole
%l%"sour cream"
%l%cheese
exit/b
:l
for %%a in (B N 2 3 3)do if %s:~0,1%==%%a shift
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1%
set s=%s:~1%
```

New rewrite saved me 81 bytes. Reading from STDIN conveniently saves a byte over using the command line. Each character of the input is processed in turn to select from a list of options; the characters `B`, `N` and `2` cause the second option to be chosen, while `3` causes the third option to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 225 Bytes

```
=rQ0s["burrito "?xGhQ"bowl "k"with:")+@,"pinto""black"shtQ" beans"+@,"brown""white"shttQ" rice"@c"steak chicken sofritas")s@Q3+@c"hot medium mild")s@Q4" salsa"seMf}\y@QhT[,5"corn\n",6"guacamole\n",7"sour cream\n",8"cheese\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 544 bytes

```
(let*((s(read-line))(l(string->list s))(lr list-ref)(d displayln)(p display)(c -1)(g(λ()(set! c(+ 1 c))(lr l c))))
(match(g)[#\A(d"burrito with:")][#\B(d"burrito bowl with:")])(match(g)[#\1(d"black beans")][#\2(d"pinto beans")])
(match(g)[#\1(d"white rice")][#\2(d"brown rice")])(match(g)[#\1(d"chicken")][#\2(d"sofritas")][#\3(d"steak")])
(match(g)[#\1(p"mild ")][#\2(p"medium ")][#\3(p"hot ")])(d"salsa")(match(g)[#\Y(d"corn")][#\N""])  
(match(g)[#\Y(d"guacamole")][#\N""])(match(g)[#\Y(d"sour cream")][#\N""])(match(g)[#\Y(d"cheese")][#\N""]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f)
  (let* ((s (read-line))
         (l (string->list s))
         (lr list-ref)
         (d displayln)
         (p display)
         (c -1)
         (g (lambda() (set! c (add1 c)) (lr l c))))
    (match (g)
      [#\A (d "burrito with:")]
      [#\B (d "burrito bowl with:")])
    (match (g)
      [#\1 (d "black beans")]
      [#\2 (d "pinto beans")])
    (match (g)
      [#\1 (d "white rice")]
      [#\2 (d "brown rice")])
    (match (g)
      [#\1 (d "chicken")]
      [#\2 (d "sofritas")]
      [#\3 (d "steak")])
    (match (g)
      [#\1 (p "mild ")]
      [#\2 (p "medium ")]
      [#\3 (p "hot ")])
    (d "salsa")
    (match (g)
      [#\Y (d "corn")]
      [#\N ""])
    (match (g)
      [#\Y (d "guacamole")]
      [#\N ""])
    (match (g)
      [#\Y (d "sour cream")]
      [#\N ""])
    (match (g)
      [#\Y (d "cheese")]
      [#\N ""])))
```

Testing:

```
(f)

burrito bowl with:
black beans
white rice
chicken
hotsalsa
corn
cheese
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 301 Bytes

```
<?="burrito".($i=$_GET[a])[0]>A?" bowl":""," with:\n".[black,pinto][$i[1]>1]." beans\n".[white,brown][$i[2]>1]." rice\n".[_,chicken,sofritas,steak][$i[3]]."\n".[_,mild,medium,hot][$i[4]]." salsa".["","\ncorn"][$i[5]>N].["","\nguacamole"][$i[6]>N].["","\nsour cream"][$i[7]>N].["","\ncheese"][$i[8]>N];
```

Previous version 311 Bytes

```
<?printf("burrito%s with:\n%s beans\n%s rice\n%s\n%s salsa%s%s%s%s",($i=$_GET[a])[0]>A?" bowl":"",[black,pinto][$i[1]>1],[white,brown][$i[2]>1],[_,chicken,sofritas,steak][$i[3]],[_,mild,medium,hot][$i[4]],["","\ncorn"][$i[5]>N],["","\nguacamole"][$i[6]>N],["","\nsour cream"][$i[7]>N],["","\ncheese"][$i[8]>N]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 737 Bytes

*Not going to win any prizes here...*

Golfed:

```
string O(string s){var c=new List<string>();var m=new Dictionary<int,List<string>>(){{0,new List<string>(){"burrito","burrito bowl"}},{1,new List<string>(){"","black beans","pinto beans"}},{2,new List<string>(){"","white rice","brown rice"}},{3,new List<string>(){"","chicken","sofritas","steak"}},{4,new List<string>(){"","mild salsa","medium salsa","hot salsa"}},{5,new List<string>(){"corn"}},{6,new List<string>(){"guacamole"}},{7,new List<string>(){"sour cream"}},{8,new List<string>(){"cheese"}},};for(int i=0;i<s.Length;i++){if(i==0){c.Add(s[0]=='A'?m[0][0]:m[0][1]+" with:");continue;}if(i>4){c.Add(s[i]=='Y'?m[i][0]:"");continue;}c.Add(m[i][int.Parse(s[i]+"")]);}return string.Join("\n",c.Where(o =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
public string O(string s)
{
  var c = new List<string>();

  var m = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()
  {
    {0, new List<string>(){"burrito", "burrito bowl"}},
    {1, new List<string>(){"", "black beans", "pinto beans"}},
    {2, new List<string>(){ "", "white rice", "brown rice"}},
    {3, new List<string>(){ "", "chicken", "sofritas", "steak"}},
    {4, new List<string>(){ "", "mild salsa", "medium salsa", "hot salsa"}},
    {5, new List<string>(){"corn"}},
    {6, new List<string>(){"guacamole"}},
    {7, new List<string>(){"sour cream"}},
    {8, new List<string>(){"cheese"}},
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      c.Add(s[0] == 'A' ? m[0][0] : m[0][1] + " with:");
      continue;
    }

    if (i > 4)
    {
      c.Add(s[i] == 'Y' ? m[i][0] : "");
      continue;
    }

    c.Add(m[i][int.Parse(s[i]+"")]);
  }

  return string.Join("\n", c.Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)));
}
```

Testing:

```
  var chipotleOrder = new ChipotleOrder();
  Console.WriteLine(chipotleOrder.P(Console.ReadLine()));
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
burrito bowl with:
black beans
white rice
chicken
hot salsa
corn
cheese
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 267

```
a=>[...a].map((c,i,a,s=x=>`
`+(','+x).split`,`[c])=>i--?i--?i--?i--?i?c>'N'?(c=i,s`corn,guacamole,sour cream,cheese`):'':s`mild,medium,hot`+' salsa':s`chicken,sofritas,steak`:s`white,brown`+' rice':s`black,pinto`+' beans':'burrito'+(c>'A'?' bowl':'')+' with:').join``
```

*Less golfed*

```
a=>
[...a].map((c,i,a,s=x=>'\n'+(','+x).split`,`[c])=>
       i--?i--?i--?i--?i?
       c>'N'?(c=i,s`corn,guacamole,sour cream,cheese`):''
       :s`mild,medium,hot`+' salsa'
       :s`chicken,sofritas,steak`
       :s`white,brown`+' rice'
       :s`black,pinto`+' beans'
       :'burrito'+(c>'A'?' bowl':'')+' with:'
).join``
```

**Test**

```js
f=
a=>[...a].map((c,i,a,s=x=>`
`+(','+x).split`,`[c])=>i--?i--?i--?i--?i?c>'N'?(c=i,s`corn,guacamole,sour cream,cheese`):'':s`mild,medium,hot`+' salsa':s`chicken,sofritas,steak`:s`white,brown`+' rice':s`black,pinto`+' beans':'burrito'+(c>'A'?' bowl':'')+' with:').join``  

function update()
{
  O.textContent=f(I.value);
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value="B1113YNNY" oninput='update()'><pre id=O></pre>
```